# create new workbook from excel tab and save to new location and close it and then grab the next tab and save to a different location using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, tabs

I am not from software background and trying to write a macro to avoid repeated work

I would like the code to grab a tab from an excel workbook create a new workbook and save it with a new name and save it to a new file and then to continue grabbing the next tab and do the same as the first step but save it to a new location. the first code below works but I need to manually change the tab each time and location can I automate this with one code with using same code but say next?

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Copysheetandsave()
    Dim sourceWs As Worksheet, savePath As String

    Set sourceWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("203")

    savePath = "C:\Users\"
    sourceWs.Copy
    With ActiveWorkbook
        .SaveAs Filename:=savePath & " 2023 YTD.xlsx"
         .Close False
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you explain in more detail e.g. share a list of source sheet names and their corresponding destination workbook names and the exact destination path (replace your name with e.g. johnsmith)?

Comment: Have a look [Splitting Sheets into Separate Workbooks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42402263/20643658). Is this cover your requirements?